# How to convert Leptonica Pix Object to Android's Bitmap

Tags: android, tesseract, android-bitmap, leptonica, tess-two

I have a Leptonica Pix object returned by

```
TessBaseApi.getThresholdedImage();
```

now, how can I convert it to bitmap so that I can show it through the `ImageView`.

`leptonica.android.Pix` to `android.graphics.Bitmap;`

I didn't find conversion methods looking at the API files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For someone with the problem I found the way after lot of searching in the source .java files:

```
import com.googlecode.leptonica.android.WriteFile;
```

and then pass the pix object to writeBitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = WriteFile.writeBitmap(pixObject);
```